# "Dar una fiesta" vs. "Hacer una fiesta"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

Me pregunto si la selección de una u otra frase es cuestión del hablante/individuo o más bien depende del dialecto que uno hable. Los libros de texto de español en estados unidos suelen incluir la primera frase con "dar" en vez de la con "hacer", pero para mi la primera variante no me suena tan común. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

No he encontrado fuentes para soportar lo que digo, pero en mi opinión tienen dos significados ligeramente distintos. Para mí, "hacer una fiesta" podría sonar a un evento un poco más informal, como acordar con tus amigos y familia y festejar. Por otro lado, "dar una fiesta" se enfoca más al hecho de que alguien, en calidad de anfitrión, organiza un evento, "ofrece" una fiesta, y podría, aunque no siempre, denotar un poco más de formalidad. Me viene a la mente con esta última expresión las fiestas que se ofrecen o dan en las casas de las familias de las novelas de Jane Austen.

Estoy de acuerdo con que, al menos en mi región (vivo en Colombia), es más común oir la expresión "hacer una fiesta".

Este es un gráfico con la frecuencia de aparición de las frases "dar una fiesta"  y "hacer una fiesta" en libros en español entre los años 1800 y 2008: [dar una fiesta,hacer una fiesta](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dar%20una%20fiesta%2Chacer%20una%20fiesta&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdar%20una%20fiesta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chacer%20una%20fiesta%3B%2Cc0), que muestra que "hacer una fiesta es más común al menos desde hace varias décadas.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu comentario, Mauricio! Y si te propongo las siguientes variantes, cuál te suena más apropriada dado el contexto? : 1.) Vamos a hacerle una fiesta de cumpleaños a su hija; 2.) Vamos a darle una fiesta de cumpleaños a su hija.

Comment: @TomLeslie ¿estas interesado en alguna región en particular? **hacerle** me suena más natural a mi también. Podrías usar **darle** cuando la fiesta en cuestión es un "regalo de cumpleaños"

Comment: Yo siempre diría "hacerle una fiesta a su hija". Porque también puedes "hacerle" una fiesta a otra persona (ej: ayer le hicimos la fiesta de despedida de soltero a mi amigo). El "darle" una fiesta a alguien en particular (yo te doy una fiesta) no me suena demasiado común, pero, como bien dices en tu pregunta, esto podría ser una cuestión del hablante, o algo regional. [edición] Acabo de leer el comentario de @DGaleano y concuerdo, se podría entender como un "obsequio", pero el "hacer" también funciona y se entiende perfectamente.

Answer (score 2):

En línea con la respuesta de Mauricio y con lo que observo en el uso, creo que la diferencia es tanto de dialectos como de connotación.

Por ejemplo, en Argentina jamás se usa *dar una fiesta* intransitivamente, sino sólo con el sentido de dar como regalo, e incluso en ese caso es más común decir *hacerle a alguien una fiesta*. La fiesta se le hace o se le da a un homenajeado (alguien que cumple años, por ejemplo); no se le da a los invitados. Para esto último tendría que decir *ofrecer una fiesta*.

Esto es en mi dialecto, sin embargo, y es obvio que la frase *dar una fiesta* sí tiene gran uso en otros.

En mi dialecto (ya me dirán los demás si en el suyo) *dar una fiesta* sugiere regalo, obsequio, ofrecimiento, y queda en la vecindad semántica de frases decididamente formales como

- *dar un banquete*
- *ofrecer una fiesta*
- *ofrecer una recepción*
- *brindar una cena de gala*

En cambio *hacer una fiesta* es, si no informal, al menos neutral. No es que al *hacer* no esté presente el *dar*, sino que el verbo *hacer* no connota en principio otra cosa que la actividad de organizar. Si se precisa indicar que la fiesta es para alguien simplemente se añade un objeto indirecto como beneficiario: por ejemplo, *Le hice una fiesta a mi hijo*.

Answer (score 0):

Hacer y dar no son los únicos verbos que puedes usar para describir la acción de preparar un evento como un fiesta. Puedes también por ejemplo **organizar** una fiesta.

Creo que se favorece el "dar" una fiesta cuando hay un motivo importante o un homenajeado (alguien a quien *agasajar* con la fiesta), pero el usar uno u otro puede ser prácticamente una elección inconsciente. Yo personalmente favorezco el "dar una fiesta".

De [acuerdo a Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dar%20una%20fiesta%2Chacer%20una%20fiesta&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=10&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdar%20una%20fiesta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chacer%20una%20fiesta%3B%2Cc0), "hacer una fiesta" supera en popularidad al "dar una fiesta". Supongo que simplemente la mayoría de libros que te has encontrado favorecen la variante del "dar" para "to throw a party".
[image]

En webs como Linguee tienes tanto "[dar una fiesta](http://www.linguee.com/spanish-english/translation/dar+una+fiesta.html)" como "[hacer una fiesta](http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/hacer+una+fiesta.html)". No hay un motivo fundamentado para que los libros de texto decidiesen usar una en lugar de la otra. Ambas son correctas, pero la popularidad puede variar de acuerdo al individuo o la zona geográfica.